# Creating a function to create multiple arrays with the same properties

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create multiple arrays that contain the same basic layout. Currently, i have

```
Array(10); //base array with moving blocks
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){ //creating an array within an array (2d)
    base[i] = new Array(22);
}
var background = new Array(10); //background array with stationary blocks
for(var z = 0; z < 10; z++){ //same as before
    background[z] = new Array(22);
}
var nextBlock = new Array(10); //next block array
for(var i = 0; i <10; i++){
    nextBlock[i] = new Array(22);
}
```

and would like to have something similar to:

```
function arrayCreator(rows,cols){
    var array = newArray(rows);
    for(var i = 0;i < rows;i++){
        array[i] = newArray(cols);
    }
}
var base = arrayCreator(10,22);
var background = arrayCreator(10,22);
var nextBlock = arrayCreator(10,22);
```

but cant get it working. How should I approach this?

Comment: you are missing return statement in arrayCreator. However you can use inbuilt array slice method to create a new copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot the return statement.

```
function arrayCreator(rows,cols){
    var array = newArray(rows);
    for(var i = 0;i < rows;i++){
        array[i] = newArray(cols);
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: "newArray" should be changed to "new Array"